# Responding queries in Nodejs when data stored in csv file

Tags: node.js, swagger, backend

THis is my first time doing web apps after a few months working in desktop applications, so i a little bit lost with this issues. Im developing a microservice in nodejs with swagger. This microservice receive request for the users with 3 parameters and these parameters allows the microservice to find a value in a excel file and return it to the user. In order to do that i have a controller called Rates who receives the request and sends to the user the selected value in the csv file.

For do that, i need to load the csv in a data structure when the server starts like a javascript Map(key,value):

- The first value of each row will be the key of the pair.
- The rest of the row will be the value of the pair, stored like an array.

I don't not experience working with nodejs, so i dont know what is the best way to do that... I have some questions:

1. It's a good solution to use a class with a global map (mapData i. e.) with two static methods, one to load the data when the server starts and another one for respond users queries searching in the dictionary the value?
2. How i can structure that in the skeleton of the project? Should I create a helper with the functions and call the load function in the app.js file using to initialize the http server and call the search function from the Rates controller?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes it's a good solution, you should absolutely read your excel file once and store it in memory with an easy-to-search format
2. You can do pretty much what you want, what I would do is the following:

   - services/CSVService.js: expose your 2 methods to read & search into the csv file
   - api/controllers: declare your controllers and call your CSVService.search() inside a controller
   - api/routes: declare your routes (referencing controllers)
   - server.js: launch the server and require the api, call the CSVService.read() once it's started